# Variables in Makefiles

Tags: variables, makefile, sphinx

I'm trying to edit a make file that controls the generation of pdf files form text files (Sphinx, if you are familiar with it). It is currently set up so that there is one make file per document (where you have one source directory and one build directory), but I'd like to tweak the directory structure, and also have just one global makefile that, when the make command is called 'make latexpdf', the pdfs are generated for all documents.

I believe this can be done by using some kind of wildcard system when defining the variables, but I'm having trouble with this.

At the moment it's set up like this: (I've included the relevant lines only)

```
BUILDDIR      = builddir  
SOURCEDIR     = sourcedir    
$(SPHINXBUILD) some options $(SOURCEDIR) $(BUILDDIR)/latex  
$(MAKE) -C $(BUILDDIR)/latex all-pdf
```

But to be able to make it go through each subdirectory in source directory, and get it to build into the subdirectories with the same name, I thought I could do something like:

```
EACHDIR       = {"subdir 1","subdir 2"}   #This is the line that I need help with.                                          
                                    #subdir refers to each document that I'm making    
BUILDDIR      = builddir/$(EACHDIR)    
SOURCEDIR     = sourcedir/$(EACHDIR)    
$(SPHINXBUILD) some options $(SOURCEDIR) $(BUILDDIR)/latex    
$(MAKE) -C $(BUILDDIR)/latex all-pdf
```

This isn't working for me, though. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
SUBDIRS = subdir1 subdir2

BUILDDIR = builddir
SOURCEDIR = sourcedir

# Define each subdir as a target
$(SUBDIRS):
    $(SPHINXBUILD) $(SOURCEDIR)/$@ $(BUILDDIR)/$@/latex
    $(MAKE) -C $(BUILDDIR)/$@/latex all-pdf

# However, these targets aren't real files, so declare them as phony
.PHONY: $(SUBDIRS)
```

This *should* work (typos notwithstanding).

However, in general you should avoid the recursive calls to Make (see [*Recursive Make Considered Harmful*](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf)).  Basically, it prevents the top-level Make from tracking the entire dependency tree, which can lead to a sub-optimal build process, and/or inconsistent rebuilds.

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind showing how it could be possible to use `make all` to allow me not to have to type each `make subdir1` etc. command for each document? Would it just be a case of nesting `$(SUBDIRS):` inside `all:` ?

Comment: @user1488804: Yes, you'd just need `all: $(SUBDIRS)`, and also `.PHONY: all`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still having trouble using this with multiple directories but I suspect these are gripes that sphinx is having in different files. Hopefully I can sort these out without too much trouble

Comment: Me again. Just one small problem using the `all: $(SUBDIRS)` command. When I then run `make all` it works in making each document as listed under the `SUBDIRS` variable, but for some reason it makes an extra subdirectory in the build directory called `all` and tries to run the build for this. Is there a way to prevent this? I wouldn't mind so much, but running the `rm` command after (within the makefile) doesn't work, leaving this rogue directory left over.

Comment: Edit: The I've made the `rm` command work so that my  directories are looking neat after the make process, but the real problem is that when it tries to make 'all' as if it were a document an error gets thrown up which terminates the make process. This is ok at the moment but will be a problem when I add more so that this isn't the last thing that needs to run. Thanks